# Apparent memory leak in recursive ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, memory-leaks

As soon as this script runs I see a steadily increasing level of CPU usage and Disk IO on the server until it eventually gets killed.

It's a script which recursively crawls a site by picking an unscraped url off the database, scraping it and adding it's links to the db.

I assume there is some kind of memory leak within the function or in the way it interacts with ActiveRecord. Is there a way I can make this more efficient and plug the leak?

```
def self.site project, operate

  @log = Logger.new(STDOUT)

  recurse = ->() do
    #
    # Pick a from the database to crawl
    unless ProjectData.where( status: 'unscraped', project_id: project[:id] ).exists?
      @log.info "No pages to scrape"
      return
    end  

    working_page = ProjectData.where( status: 'unscraped', project_id: project[:id]).first
    working_page.status = 'processing'
    working_page.save

    @log.info "Scraping #{working_page.url}"
    #
    #   Scape it
    data, links = OutriderTools::Scrape::page( working_page.url, operate)

    unless links.nil? 
      links.each  do |link|
        # Check if link already exists
        #if ProjectData.find_by(url: link.to_s).nil?
        unless ProjectData.where( url: link.to_s, project_id: project[:id] ).exists?  
          ProjectData.create({
            :url        => link.to_s,
            :status     => 'unscraped',
            :project_id => project[:id]
          })
          @log.info "Adding new url to database: #{link.to_s}"
        else
          @log.info "URL already exists in database: #{link.to_s}"
        end
      end
    end

    @log.info "Saving page data for url #{working_page.url}"
    @log.info data[:status]
    working_page.update( data ) unless data.nil?

    recurse.call

  end

  recurse.call

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a thought, not an answer:

I hope you are aware that by using recursion, you keep all the collected data and variables in the memory - they are NEVER released UNTIL the recursion ends.

For instance, both the `working_page` and `links` variables stay alive in the memory (along with the DB ActiveRecord class) while new `working_page` and `links` variables are created within the recursive name-space.

There might be no memory leak, just an issue of design.

Unless you need that data again after the recursion - which you don't seem to - it would be better to use a `while` loop:

```
working_page = nil
while (working_page = ProjectData.where( status: 'unscraped', project_id: project[:id] ).first)
   # ... do your thing...
end
```

(the `=` is not a mistake. It's used as an assignment and the whole assignment is reviewed to check that `working_page` has an object that exists and is assigned to it)

Comment: This is the answer to my Disk IO and CPU issues. Changing to a while loop has brought both these stats down to reasonable levels and they aren't climbing. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome, but I have to give credit to @peter for his insight. I wrote my answer after reading his and I don't know if I would have thought about this issue without his reminder.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first point you to [this article](http://blog.skylight.io/hunting-for-leaks-in-ruby/?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email) I recently read about memory leakage, it is part of the wonderful Ruby Weekly newsletter.

That sead, it is mostly advcanced stuff and the more traditional easy approach works faster most of the time.

In my opinion, the most likely source of the problem is the recursion, get rid of that.

There are some parts of your code that could be more streamlined also. eg

```
working_page = ProjectData.where( status: 'unscraped', project_id: project[:id]).first
    working_page.status = 'processing'
    working_page.save
```

could be

```
working_page = ProjectData.where( status: 'unscraped', project_id: project[:id]).first_or_create(status: 'processing')
```

The same trick with

```
unless ProjectData.where( url: link.to_s, project_id: project[:id] ).exists?  
          ProjectData.create({
            :url        => link.to_s,
            :status     => 'unscraped',
            :project_id => project[:id]
          })
```

could be (and don't mix old and new notations of hashes)

```
hash = {url: link.to_s, status: 'unscraped', project_id: project[:id]})
ProjectData.where(hash).first_or_create(hash.merge({status: 'unscraped'}))
```

You can get rid of the last extra level by using

```
return if links.nil?
```

You'd better comment out all the stuff that is not absolutely necessary, eg the logging and even the saving to database, start with a few lines and see it that works without increasing the memory, then build up by removing the comments.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Thanks, I'll have a refactor based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to set the status to other than unscraped when finishing with
a page. To me it is not clear what working_page.update( data ) unless data.nil?
does. Also I see no point in using recursion. You could use an infinite loop and break when there are no more pages. Using recursion probably fills up the memory
pretty quickly.
Most such scripts are slow and could cause a timeout when executed by a web server. You should run the script as some kind of scheduled job.

Comment: Thanks, data is a hash of fields to update in the db, including it's status as scraped or not.

Comment: If you set the status again to unscraped, a page will be processed again and again and again. That probably happens if the page cannot be scraped. That can lead to a very long running time.